# Why isn't Random walk with trend non-stationary according to ADF?

Tags: time-series, hypothesis-testing, stationarity, trend, random-walk

A random walk with trend doesn't have unit root. So, null hypothesis will be rejected. Hence, according to alternative hypothesis, since it doesn't have unit root, it will become stationary process as unit root tests are used for non-stationary test. However, all random walks are non-stationary. Isn't this is a contradiction ? What I am missing here.

Comment: Do you know the concept of type I, II errors? In general,  testing statistical hypotheses is not like a mathematical proof -- the outcome does not "prove" anything logically.

Comment: Your question ostensibly is about a mathematical model: a "random walk with trend."  It doesn't refer to data.  What role could there possibly be for hypothesis testing, then?

Answer (score 2):

> A random walk with trend doesn't have unit root.

The premise is incorrect. A random walk with trend does have a unit root. It is
$$
x_t=c+\color{red}1\cdot x_{t-1}+u_t
$$
where $u_t$ is i.i.d. or at least not autocorrelated. This is an AR(1) process where the AR(1) coefficient is 1, thus it has a unit root. To see this more clearly, you can also rewrite this as
$$
(1-\color{red}1\cdot L)x_t=c+u_t
$$
where $L$ is the lag operator.

Answer (score 0):

I am no expert on time series, but I am pretty sure what you are missing is not about time series, but about null hypothesis testing. You wrote

> A random walk with trend doesn't have unit root. So, null hypothesis
> will be rejected.

This is not necessarily so. It depend on how big the trend is and how big the sample is. And also what level of significance you select.

Comment: But there can be a case when a random walk with trend doesn't have unit root. Right ?

Comment: "Doesn't have a unit root" is different from "has one that is significantly different from 1."

If you look at enough decimal places, surely no real world time series (or even an artificially simulated one) has *exactly* unit root.